# Error occured processing XML 'org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler'

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I'm completely new to Spring, I just created a Spring Legacy Project with Spring Tool Suite 3.9.0 and Spring framework 4.3.10, and I don't find the solution anywhere to this error "Error occured processing XML 'org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler' servlet-context.xml". Here is what the .log says:

```
!ENTRY org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core 1 0 2017-08-19 11:53:15.584
!MESSAGE Error occured processing '/sir/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml'
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.ResourcesBeanDefinitionParser.registerResourceHandler(ResourcesBeanDefinitionParser.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.ResourcesBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ResourcesBeanDefinitionParser.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.namespaces.DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver$ElementTrackingNamespaceHandler.parse(DelegatingNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ErrorSuppressingBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeansConfig.java:1434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$ToolingFriendlyBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:1363)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.registerBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:410)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$2.loadBeanDefinitions(BeansConfig.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:453)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.internal.model.BeansConfig$3.call(BeansConfig.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2017-08-19 11:53:15.596
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2017-08-19 11:53:15.600
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2017-08-19 11:53:15.608
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.lsp4e 1 0 2017-08-19 11:53:15.737
!MESSAGE Non IFiles not supported yet
```

the pom.xml file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>sir</artifactId>
    <name>SIR</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.3.10.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.25</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add your `pom.xml` to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem lies in multiple usage of spring-web dependency. It is already included in spring-webmvc dependency. Try removing dependency for spring-web. It should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceHttpRequestHandler
```

This says that your project is missing `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` which resides in `spring-webmvc` artifact.

Make sure you have it in your pom.xml, something like this:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have that dependency but with the version 3.2.18, I changed the version to the 4.3.10 but nothing changed.

Comment: Also make sure that the maven dependencies are updated to the project.  Right click on the project, then select Maven and click on Update Project, after that try to run the project again.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help either. Apparently must be something with the 4.3.10 version, so I tried with the previous version 4.2.9 and the errors disappeared.